# How do Scala acquire its JVM environment?

Tags: java, scala

Dev env: Scala 2.11.8, JDK 1.8.112 x64, Windows 7 x64.

- updated JDK to the latest version [JDK 1.8.112](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- uninstalled Scala 2.11.7 and installed [Scala 2.11.8](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.11.8.html)
- reboot

**Problem**: Scala still sees the previous JDK 1.8.101 instead of the new one 1.8.112.

```
C:\Users\myUserName>java -version
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)

C:\Users\myUserName>scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_101).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> System.getProperty("java.version")
res3: String = 1.8.0_101
```

The reason is the new JDK is installed in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112` while the previous JDK is in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8`. **JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8**. So I suppose this is why Scala sees the previous version. However, PATH

```
C:\Users\myUserName>PATH
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath; 
... etc...
C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\bin;
```

C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath contains java.exe which comes from the newest JDK. This is why java -version at the command line show the latest JDK.

**Question**: On Windows, how to make the latest JDK the official JDK? And generally, what is the recommended practice to update JDK on Windows?

Comment: Is your `JAVA_HOME` set? Your Scala version has generally nothing to do with the way your OS is finding it's Java version.

Comment: What is the output of the command `set`? Was `1.8.0.101` in the path first?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have edited the question to give more details about JAVA_HOME and PATH env variables. I think the issue is mainly my unfamiliarity with Windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

The `java` command executes `java.exe` file from the **first folder** of the `PATH` environment variable where this file is found.

On the other hand `scala` command executes `scala.bat` batch file and this file set the java environment for scala by `JAVA_HOME` environment variable if it exists.

The problem is that in *almost every system* is the file `java.exe` in **many different folders** - some of them may be subfolders of other program folders (i. e. from Adobe or JetBrains products) which you had installed previously.

The file name is the same but versions may be (and in most cases *are*) different.

And the recommended practice for upgrading? **Install and pray** ([Oracle itself has problems with it](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/choosing_64_and_or_32)) or install and then manually adjust every application which depends from Java.